# How to get current route in zend 2 framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

How to check in index action If I am at www.sample.com/test not at www.sample.com/test/qqqq or www.sample.com/test?testget=fdfdf&testget2=fdfdfdf or at others sites just only at www.sample.com/test ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$event = $this->getEvent();

$event->getRouteMatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

In zf1 this was straightforward with applicationPath or rootPath but in zf2 this has changed.

Found more information here http://samminds.com/2012/08/why-root_path-is-not-needed/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In a view you can use

```
echo $this->serverUrl(true);
```

You can also use view helpers in a controller

```
$viewHelperManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager'); 

$myHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('serverUrl');
```